# 2006 BMW E 60 525I engine oil level sensor giving faulty reading

Tags: sensor

The electronic oil level sensor is giving a faulty indication, by using E 20 engine flush chemical, can I clean the sensor and clear the fault?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you please specify what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Looks like dude just asked if you can use E20 flush to clean an oil level sensor in a 525i. That's what I got, anyway.

Comment: Clean the sensor and check the connections - if the fault is still there then cleaning did not work... Replace...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to replace the oil level sensor, the sensors go bad internally and cleaning will not fix it, do a google search and you will see that it's a common problem.